# Random og image and title set

Tags: php, jquery, facebook-opengraph

I saw this on a website at f-u-t-b-o-l.com wherein on each refresh the image and title set changes. For eg:- at one time on FB, it shows `og:image` as say Messi.jpg and during the session, the `og:title` says "Messi." I could figure out randomising the image a little each session with the tutorial here - https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29023594/How-to-Show-Random-Image-in-Meta-og-image-Tag-on-every-refresh.html , but how do I set an image and a related title for each refresh? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function myrnd(_a, _b){
     a = parseInt(_a)||0;
     b = parseInt(_b)||0;
     return Math.floor( Math.random() * (a - b + 1) ) + b;
 }

 var titles ={
               0:'title 0',
               1:'title 1',
               2:'title 2',
               3:'title 3',
               4:'title 3',
               };



 var my_rnd=myrnd(0,4);

 document.title = titles[my_rnd];
```